# How can I do an update import in Quick Base from a csv without importing null values?

Tags: csv, import, quickbase

I need a way to update a Quick Base table with a csv update import, but I don't want to over-write existing data in the Quick Base table with null values in the csv. I want to only import the non-null data from the csv.

I would like to do regular updates of a Quick Base table by uploading a CSV. However, my csv will only include values for data that is changing from the existing records. Most of the values in the csv will be null.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

How are you uploading the csv?

The most important thing to know is that you need to provide record IDs for each item in your csv to match them with existing records, otherwise Quickbase writes new records. You also need to format your clist properly. So...

You can narrow down what will be written by including Record IDs in your csv rows. If your csv contains Record IDs then only the matching Record IDs will be updated. You can optionally use `mergefield` instead of record ID. This is a new feature as of a few months ago.

If you need to update individual fields per record and exclude other fields, then specify only the fields that should get updated in the clist, ex: clist='3.7.11.31' (include record id so that it can match the existing records).

If you will have a mix of records and fields where some are supposed to be updated, and some aren't then you could go through the csv to import with something like javascript. For example: you can do `API_DoQuery` with a clist that matches your csv's clist (or `'a'` for all). Let the results of that API call be the csv you will upload later, then update that csv with the csv you want to upload. That way you'll have a copy of the data from Quickbase, and then with the updated values in your csv, do `API_ImportFromCSV`.

see the [documentation](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/importfromcsv.html) on using the API call for more help.